# "constructible but not definable"

Tags: logic, set-theory

T. Jech in his monograph Ch. 18, p. 301 writes "... the set T is constructible, but not definable in L."  My guess is that this means that T (a subset of, say, some ordinal) is definable in some structure $L_\alpha$ to which it does not belong, by a formula with some parameters, - but is not definable in any structure $L_\beta$, by a formula without parameters. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means: $T$ is constructible, it belongs to $L$. However, it is not definable (in $L$) without parameters (in particular, the definition given in that page uses the parameter $\aleph_1^V$). Nowadays, this usage of "definable" is non-standard, and it would have been better to be explicit in the text by writing instead "definable without parameters".

Comment: In connection with the last line of the question: It's possible for a set to be definable (without parameters) in some $L_\beta$ yet not be definable (without parameters) in $L$. The point is that $\beta$ might not be definable (without parameters) in $L$.

Comment: Thank you Andres and Andreas for helping me to create an island  of clarity!
(And, model-theoretically,  by "definable in $L$" we mean a definable class which is a member (and hence a set)?)

Comment: - rather "a singleton," than "a member."